# Is it possible to include a database view in a JPA/EclipseLink CriteriaQuery?

Tags: jpa-2.0, eclipselink, h2

I am working on a project that needs to be able to create dynamic queries into an H2 database. This also includes a full text search with built-in H2 logic, tables, and triggers.

I have been trying to figure out how to add that full-text search into my CriteriaQuery but keep running into the road block that the tables used aren't entities in my model. I could add them as entities, but I don't want them created automatically by EclipseLink when a new database file is created since there is a function in H2 that creates the tables and does other necessary housekeeping.

I had tried the path of creating a view to query the full text tables to give me the information I need in the format I need. But I still keep running into the same problem that that view is not an Entity.

Has anyone encountered this situation before and/or figured out a way around it?

Thanks!